# Specify a Keypress as a variable for "if" command

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, variable, read

Before continuing, please bear in mind that I am aware that I could configure keyboard shortcuts through the settings menu, but that would not be of use for my end goal.

I'm trying to create a simple script to take a single keypress as the input, then perform an action. Ideally, I would like to execute a command when I press the `up` key.

While I could integrate, for example, the `x` key as follows:

```bash
echo "press key"
read -sn 1 key
if [ "$key" == "x" ]; then echo "x"; fi
```

I'm struggling to find out how to use the `up` key where the `x` is in this example. 
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: In the console "up" is neither a single byte, nor a single character. It may be `^[[A` where `^[` [denotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) the ESC character (octal `033`, hex `1b`). To see it press Ctrl+v, then up. Try Ctrl+v with other keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

read -p "press key " -sn 1 key 
#you can use -p "Message" instead of using echo "Message" before.

if [ "$key" == $'\x1b' ]; then
   
   read -sn2 chars

   if [[ $chars = '[A' ]];then
      echo You pressed 'Up' key
   fi
else 
   echo Pressed another key
fi
```

When you type keys like `Up key`,`Right key`, `Left key`, `Down Key`, `Fn+N` this generates the string `x1\b`. So you have to check if the variable contains that string, if so then you should read the following two characters:

1. `[A` is for Up key
2. `[C` is for Right key
3. `[B` is for Down key
4. `[D` is for Left key

Comment: Note other keys may generate `$'\x1b'` and e.g. 3 or 4 additional characters, so blindly reading 2 after `$'\x1b'` is not a good logic *in general*. Sole Esc key generates `$'\x1b'`. To distinguish Up from Esc followed by `[A` *typed* by the user, a program should analyze the delay between `$'\x1b'` and whatever follows. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1579208/432690).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What about using `xxd -p`? does it have the same issue? I thinking in a second possible solution but I'm not sure if `xxd` might have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With a bit of tweaking, I've been able to get it to do what I wanted.